# How to set up a local Wordpress site?

Tags: software-installation, localhost, wordpress

I want to create a site based on Wordpress that is only accessible from my own machine (localhost). In other words, I do not want my computer to be a server. I just want it to have all the files necessary for a website in `/var/www/`, so that I can later copy-paste those files an another machine which will be a server.

Therefore I installed the wordpress package and I am about to install a graphical interface to manage the files. What should I do? Do I need somthing called LAMP?

I have seen [this question on WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32331/wordpress-local-development-environment), but I wonder if someone could provide instructions that are more Ubuntu specific or easier to follow, especially if they are relevant to the Unity interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sudo tasksel` to install a local LAMP server.

After selecting LAMP you can install it (you may need to scroll down the list to find the 'OK' button) and while installing, tasksel will ask you for the password for the MySQL installation (which is very important not to forget!).

Then you can open your browser and type `http://localhost` and you should see **It works**.

Comment: +1 for using tasksel -- ubuntu / debian specific systems implement this type of "automagic" setup.

Comment: "Automagic" meaning that I should not do any configuration after the installation?

Comment: So, in Tasksel I have the "LAMP server" option checked. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

## 2016 solution

A very good guide can be found from mentioned urls at the bottom.
Here is a breakdown for you,

### install mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

### Install Apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
```

after installing mysql and apache you should get localhost up and running. Try to check/verify from browser by typing `localhost` as a URL. Now, lets get started with WordPress installation.

### Installing WordPress

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf latest.tar.gz –strip-components=1
```

(use sudo) if required.

Then using the sudo command set the permissions so you will be able to modify the files and allow the web server to access them as well like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data *
sudo chgrp -R www-data *
```

After all of this, It's time to create database in mysql, i will show a short way to do it ;)

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO “wordpress”@”localhost” IDENTIFIED BY “foopassword”;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> EXIT
```

Don't forget to do necessary changes such as username and database name change according to your desire. After doing mysql thing, Rename the wp-config-sample.php file to wp-config.php from your wordpress folder and using your favorite text editor you will need to add the name of your database, mysql username and password to the config file.

If you had follow the instructions correctly, then its your lucky day :)
you can now simply browser your wp site by navigating to `localhost/yourfoldername`

Reference Urls: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04 
http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/ubuntu-apache-php-mysql-wordpress/

Comment: Readers should note that though it says 2016 solution, this won't work for 16.04 (and one of the sources indicates its for 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

First install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), then unzip wordpress.zip and change permissions. It should be made writable. Do not edit `config-sample.php` file.

Create a database using PHPMyAdmin, then move the unzipped folder to xampp directory. Start XAMPP, open up your web browser and type `localhost/xampp/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php`.

Follow the instructions. Leave the password field empty and database prefix empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to try [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374)

It turns your computer into a "private server" you can use, with MySQL and Apache technologies. All the instructions are on the website. I hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Wordpress website on localhost using XAMPP is the best solution you have. It gives you an option to explore themes and plugins as well.

Step 1 – Install XAMPP
[image: XAMPP control panel]

Once you have launched XAMPP you have control panel from which you can start programs. If you have any port errors fix those errors first. For fixing port errors and start XAMPP to [install WordPress on Locahost XAMPP](https://www.wpblog.com/launch-wordpress-localhost-using-xampp/). Then you should go to phpmyadmin to create a database.

For installation of WordPress you must follow a guide that will definitely gives you a step by step guidance.